# Cluster symbol color based on categorised variables

Tags: qgis

I'm making a categorized point map with QGIS. I'm using the categorized symbol and qualitative color palette. I need to group the points into clusters. Unfortunately I can't create clusters based on categories in a single layer. (the color assistant accept only numeric values).

[image]

However, on this post and this screenshot it seems possible...

https://north-road.com/qgis-cluster-renderer-crowdfunding/

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is as stated in the linked NORTHROAD website...... A step-by-step version would be:

1. Select `Point cluster`
2. Click on `Cluster symbol`
3. On the `Cluster symbol` dialog window, click and highlight `Simple marker`
4. Click on the `Epsilon` (or Big e) icon and select `Edit`
5. In the `Expression String Builder` window, type-in **@cluster_color**. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great ! It works well